# need to resize file system to 98% of itself.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

A computer problem...but really math in disguise.

I have a file system that has used 105076 of space.  I need to resize the file system so that 105076 is 98% of x.  How do I find x?

Comment: $\frac{98}{100}\ast x=105076\Rightarrow x=\frac{105076\ast 100}{98}\Rightarrow x=\frac{105076\ast 50}{49}$

Answer (score 1):

Since $105076\;$ is $98\%$ of $x$, then $0.98*x = 105076\;\;$. This means $x = 105076/0.98 = 107220.4\;\;\;$.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to think about problems like these is to first work out what *one* per cent is: you have $98\%$ so you just need to divide by $98$. Then you want to find out what $100\%$ is, so you multiply by $100$.

There are slightly more direct ways to do it when you understand percentages better. But the above way is intuitive and flexible.